# visual studio 2010 "surround with" hijacked by "pex and moles"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pex-and-moles, surround

After I installed "[Pex and Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/)", used for automated testing, my "Surround with" (ctrl + k, s) in Visual Studio 2010 has been "hijacked" by the new add on.

This means I can only choose to insert a "PexClass for MSTest", which is kind of annoying since I use surround with many times each day.

Hope someone can help to reset this feature to its original functionality without removeing Pex and Moles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the menu `Tools -> Options`
Then select `Environment -> Keyboard`

In the shortcut field, press `CTRL+K, S`. You'll see all bindings for this combination. Adjust or remove the ones you don't like.

[image: Keyboard options]

Comment: Thanks for this. I fixed it by removing Pex and Moles but it happend again with Code Contracts, and the way descirped gives me the oppertunati to fix it.